# Can I Upload 3 APKs At Once to Play Store?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-play, apk

My app uses Firebase and Flutter (auth, cloud_firestore, google_sign_in...).
And when I upload it to Play Store with App Bundle using this command:
`flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64`
My app does not work properly with Firebase, there are no logs and crash reports.
But when I use APK it works.
So I released several APK files using this command: `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi`, my question is is it possible to upload those 3 files to the same app on Play Store?
It gives me a warning too:

```
Unoptimized APK
Warning:

This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.

Resolution:

Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.
```

What should I do? (I prefer to use APK because my app works with APK)

packages:

```
  google_sign_in: 4.5.1
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
```

app/build.gradle (android->defaultConfig) I commented the NDK section because APK doesn't allow with it.

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
        // ndk {
        //     abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        // }
    }

    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at officiel documentation  https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk

Comment: ok, some parts were understood. Do you have an idea to how to ``flutter run`` with app bundle to check if my app works properly with an app bundle?

Comment: you can generate mulitple apks with bundletool .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend this, 3 strikes and you are out. If you've made a mistake that unintentionally breaches Terms and Conditions and you get one app pulled because of it then you can correct the issue and resubmit but if you have the same issue with all three then they will all be pulled and your account will be banned. This is so easy to do, so I recommend only one at a time, leave it a week between each upload. I had this happen to me when I unintentially left a link to my own app repository, it wasn't even a visible link, but external links were against T&C's at the time and probably still are. They will not talk to you and you have no recourse so be very careful.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a warning to let you know about the size of your APKs being unnecessarily large, this isn't a blocking error. If you can't publish your app, this isn't the reason: make sure you have filled all the store listing (with images), ticked all the boxes, filled in the privacy policy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload several APKs for the same App as long as they target different architectures. I'm doing the same for my apps. The warning above can be ignored.